# convert Cefsharp offscreen to winform

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

Is it possible to convert `cefsharp.offscreen` `browser` to `cefsharp.winform` ?

In my project I want to work with `offscreen` but sometime need to see what happened in browser so i need to show browser for small time ...

Also i know i can use from `cefsharp.winform` and load page/browser in new winform and then after create form hide that however I want minimal usage of ram,cpu,etc so I think `offscreen` is better for performance.

so if i can convert offscreen to winform i can show browser only when i need and etc...so have any solution ?

Comment: For reference you can use devtools even with the OffScreen version.

Comment: @amaitland that is not good for my project, personally I don't need for devtools,or winforms browser however user don't know anything about html or etc so need for winforms browser, i want to convert to winform for this ...

Comment: As I said for reference, it's very helpful tool for debugging. If you don't know anything about HTML then learn and fast....

Comment: @amaitland : Hah... Don't read correctly, I know ! but my user/customer don't know....anyway..thanks